# How to debug python script started with python27.dll from gVim?

Tags: python, debugging, vim, python-mode, rope

I am using gVim on windows 7.
I am trying to investigate why rope (as part of python-mode plugin) shows me a lot of errors when I trying to use auto complete feature.

```
Opening [C:windowssystem32] project ...  
Error detected while processing function RopeCodeAssistInsertMode..RopeCodeAssist:
line    1:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
And so on...
```

gVim uses python27.dll for evaluating python code.

Are there ways for debugging gVim plugins? 
Can I to attach to gVim for debug python code, evaluated from gVim?

Comment: @JoelVroom No. This is for debugging cpython interpreter itself, question asks about debugging scripts. One can, of course, use lower level to debug scripts, but using gdb for this purpose is a pure waste of time if one can use pdb.

Comment: Thanks ZyX...I stand corrected...comment deleted.